# Error when deploying Node application to Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

Good morning, sorry for your time, but it really is important. I was trying to upload my application "MEAN JS", but I get errors when uploading it to heroku. I will be very grateful for your contributions. Thank you very much.

This is the structure of my project, you can also see the errors shown by heroku:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fbY3.png)

This is my node package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "Crabbit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.14.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.8",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

And this is my package.json from angular:

```js
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngmodule/material-carousel": "^0.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

And this is the code of my file "index.js"

```js
const express=require('express');
const config=require('./config/config');
const app =config(express()); 
const morgan=require('morgan');
const cors=require('cors');


const multer = require('multer');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
const path = require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, 'public/img/uploads'),
    filename: (req, file, cb, filename) => {

        cb(null, uuid() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
}) 
app.use(multer({storage}).single('image'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//Iniciando el servidor
app.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log('Server on port',app.get('port')); 
});

//Llamar a la base de datos
require('./database');

//Funciones

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json()); // Reconocer el formato JSON 
app.use(cors({origin:'http://localhost:4200'}));
```

my project files :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbLMm.png)

Comment: Can i have a screenshot of the error?

Comment: As per the exception it is saying "app/index.js" module not found. Can you please tell where this file is located, I am not able to see that in your project

Comment: MatthewProSkils At the beginning of my question is the image, you must click the link.    Vimal Patel 
It's weird because it's looking for that file in that "app /" path. As you can see that file is in the server folder.
It should say "server / index.js", but no.